# Permission Users to Add (including tagging of columns) but not Edit or Delete Documemts

Tags: sharepoint-online, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level, column-settings

Is there a way to permission users to add a document and **edit tags** but but does not allow the user to edit and delete documents?

I have created a custom permission level with these list permissions.  Users assigned to this permission can add documents but cannot edit tags/columns.  Is this possible to permission?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible as users who can edit the metadatas of documents can definitely edit the document. This is by design.

You can share your idea to our development team via this feedback portal: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback.